# Undefined reference to operator>> results in LINK2019

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've overloaded the `operator>>` to read from file like so:

**matrix.h**

```
class Matrix {
   // member functions
};
// declared outside the class
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const Matrix& rhs);
```

**matrix.cpp**

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& rhs)
{
    std::string line;
    std::istringstream iss;

    std::getline(is, line); // grab first line
    iss.str(line);

    // Follows:
    //  http://http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector
    //  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator
    // Avoids:
    //  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse
    std::vector<int> dim( (std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)),
                           std::istream_iterator<int>() );

    rhs.setRows(dim[0]);
    rhs.setCols(dim[1]);

    int curr_r = 0;
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        iss.str(line);
        std::vector<double> row( (std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)),
                                  std::istream_iterator<int>() );
        rhs.insRow(curr_r, row);
        curr_r++;
    }
    return is;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    Matrix M;
    while (inf >> M) {}
    return 0;
}
```

I declared it outside the class per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) SO post. Using VS2017 I am receiving the [LINK2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK2019)%26rd%3Dtrue) error and when I try to compile I get:

```
undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, Matrix const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought I had appropriate declared/defined my `operator>>` overload. Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Function signatures must exactly match!

Comment: @TheDude Yea I just saw with the answer post...cant believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, Matrix const&)'
```

There's no defined operator with `Matrix const &` argument.

Since you declare the operator for `const Matrix &`, you must *define* it for `const Matrix &`, not

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& rhs)
{
 . . . 
}
```

Just add const:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,const Matrix& rhs)
{
 . . . 
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see the copy-paste error from my `operator<<` definition. Simple solution to an obvious error.

Comment: My first guess was that you didn't actually include the cpp file in the build/link stage.